# Change cube face color in threejs with clickevent

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, three.js

I try to change cube face color when click to face like this :

```
document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;

            raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(cube);

            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                    var hex = Math.random() * 0xffffff;

                    if(intersects[0].face.normal.x==0 && intersects[0].face.normal.y==0 &&intersects[0].face.normal.z==-1){
                        intersects[0].face.color.setHex(hex);
                        geometry.faces[intersects[0].face.materialIndex].color.setHex(hex);
                        console.log(intersects[0].face);
                    }
                    if(intersects[0].face.normal.x==0 && intersects[0].face.normal.y==0 &&intersects[0].face.normal.z==1){
                        intersects[0].face.color.setHex(hex);
                        geometry.faces[intersects[0].face.materialIndex].color.setHex(hex);
                        console.log(intersects[0].face);
                    }
                    if(intersects[0].face.normal.x==1 && intersects[0].face.normal.y==0 &&intersects[0].face.normal.z==0){
                        intersects[0].face.color.setHex(hex);
                        geometry.faces[intersects[0].face.materialIndex].color.setHex(hex);
                        console.log(intersects[0].face);
                    }
                    if(intersects[0].face.normal.x==0 && intersects[0].face.normal.y==-1 &&intersects[0].face.normal.z==0){
                        intersects[0].face.color.setHex(hex);
                        geometry.faces[intersects[0].face.materialIndex].color.setHex(hex);
                        console.log(intersects[0].face);
                    }
                    if(intersects[0].face.normal.x==-1 && intersects[0].face.normal.y==0 &&intersects[0].face.normal.z==0){
                        intersects[0].face.color.setHex(hex);
                        geometry.faces[intersects[0].face.materialIndex].color.setHex(hex);
                        console.log(intersects[0].face);
                    }
                    if(intersects[0].face.normal.x==0 && intersects[0].face.normal.y==1 &&intersects[0].face.normal.z==0){
                        intersects[0].face.color.setHex(hex);
                        geometry.faces[intersects[0].face.materialIndex].color.setHex(hex);
                        console.log(intersects[0].face);
                    }
            }       
        }
```

But when I click the face it does not change color.Any ideas?

Comment: (1) in your cube material set `cube.material.vertexColors = THREE.FaceColors;` (2) if you change a face color, set `cube.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;` You may have other problems...